# Grunt Uglify source map "unable to write"

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using Grunt to concat and minify files (with grunt-contrib-uglify and grunt-contrib-concat ) and I wanted to add a source map. The uglify docs say to just add an option for sourceMap set to a boolean of true. But when I add that to my tasks (I've tried a couple different ones) the process runs fine until it gets to the source map part, then I get:

> Writing true...ERROR
>
> Warning: Unable to write "true" file (Error code: undefined). Use --force to continue.

The concatenation is done, the minification is done. But... no luck with the sourcemap.

Sample from my Grunt file:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= pkg.version %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
  },
  publicjs: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true
    },
    files: {
      'js/<%= pkg.name %>_public.min.js': ['<%= concat.publicjs.dest %>']
    }
  }
}
```

(I've also tried with the sourceMap in my top level options object.)

Any ideas? Clearly Grunt can write to the directory because it creates the concatenated and minified files, and I can't think of what else might be the trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Section " Migrating from 2.x to 3.x" mentions this:

> sourceMap - Only accepts a Boolean value. Generates a map with a
>   default name for you

So it looks like you are using an older version with the new version's config options.

- You can upgrade.
- Or use the older version's config options. (I think you should assign the destination file name to this variable instead of true. But I didn't verify in the old version's documentation.)

Comment: Oh, duh. I ran npm update, but (I'm new to node) didn't realize it wasn't just updating to the newest version (guess I need to look up better how to define that in package.json). Thanks.

Comment: The example code IS using a boolean for `SourceMap` so what's the fix?

Comment: The OP's (old) version expects a file name in the configuration variable sourceMap, not a boolean.The newer version expects the boolean.